# Как оптимизировать вложенные циклы?

Tags: python, циклы, numpy, for, теория-вероятностей

Имеется список случайно выпавших чисел (0 или 1) длиною в 10000 элементов. В записи это выглядит так: `X = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10000)` (задача с подбрасыванием монеты).

Нужно рассчитать вероятность получения 0 или 1 для каждого количества экспериментов, в данном случае - подбрасываний. Например, при количестве 10000 подбрасываний получаем 4994 результата '1'. Это получилось рассчитать с помощью:

```
y = {i:list(X[0:10000]).count(i) for i in list(X[0:10000])}
```

На этой основе написал цикл, внутри которого оказался и этот цикл:

```
lst = []
for i in range(1,len(X)+1):
    y = {j:list(X[0:i]).count(j) for j in list(X[0:i])}
    lst.append(y[1]/i)
```

Понятное дело, что это не решает мою задачу.
Подскажите, как это можно оптимизировать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А `sum(X)/len(X)` разве не то же самое? Т.е. так:

```
for i in range(1,len(X)+1):
    prob = sum(X[:i])/len(X[:i]) 
    lst.append(prob)
```

И даже еще проще, чтоб не считать сумму десять тысяч раз:

```
X = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10000) 
lst = []
s = 0
for i in range(len(X)):
    s += X[i]
    prob = s/(i+1) 
    lst.append(prob)
```

Выполняется за 0,5-1 мс.

Answer (score 9):

Если уж пользоваться `Numpy`, то тогда лучше в полной мере, вообще без "чистого питона", делаем все операции через `Numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10000)
res = np.cumsum(X)/np.arange(1, 10001)
```

То есть копим сумму выпадающих значений и делим её значение на каждом шаге суммирования на число экспериментов - и всё это средствами `Numpy`, очень быстро, порядка 0.1мс.

```
103 µs ± 263 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 7):

Вы проставили тег Numpy, но совсем им не пользуютесь ;)

```
X = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10000)

res = [X[:i].mean() for i in range(1, len(X))]
```

Замер скорости:

```
In [19]: %timeit res = [X[:i].mean() for i in range(1, len(X))]
86.2 ms ± 621 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: почему-то намного дольше, чем просто складывать и делить без использвания нампи

Comment: @Эникейщик, потому что "магия" здесь не нужна :D. В моем варианте среднее считается для каждого среза, что гораздо более накладно по сравнению с вашим накопительным вариантом